# How to perform a pre select in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, event-driven, tablegateway

I have a `AbstractTableGateway` like this:

```
class FundsTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{

protected $table = 'tb_funds';

public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet(new FundsHydrator(), new Fund());
    $this->initialize();
}

public function fetchAll($year)
{
    $select = new Select(array("f" => $this->table));
    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
    $resultSet->initialize($resultSet->toArray());
    return $resultSet;
}

}
```

And i would like to check something before return the `$resultSet` in `fetchAll` method, but i have a lot of this methods and dont want to put a if or a where in each of them, would like to make a function uncoupled of the class, i tried to use a `EventFeature` of `TableGateway` but the zend is lack of documentation about that.

Did you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that,

In model jut add the `EventFeature` feature on construct:

```
$this->featureSet = new FeatureSet();
$this->featureSet->addFeature(new EventFeature());
```

And then in your `Module.php` you ll need to create a `SharedEventManager`. That's because when the model instantiate the `EventFeature` this create a **new** `EventManager` inside that, different from `EventManager` that the Zend create in bootstrap, so you just need to create that and attach a following event:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
  $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
  $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

  $sharedEventManager->attach(
        'Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway',
        EventFeature::EVENT_PRE_SELECT,
        function (EventFeature\TableGatewayEvent $e) {
            //Do stuff here or call some method
  });
}
```